# SUSE on hyper-v boots to emergency mode after copying its vhdx file form old drive to new drive

Tags: linux, suse, hyper-v

I am not very Linux savvy, but am trying to do my best here.

I had a functioning SUSE Enterprise server SP2 VM running on Hyper-V. I decided to replace the old mechanical hard drive with a new SSD. After copying the hyper-v folder over and starting the VM, I now get the following notice:

```
You are running in emergency mode.
```

I can put in my admin password, but no gui.
If I start SUSE in Advanced mode and select the non-default kernel restore mode, I get the same Emergency Mode notice, but it shows some other error in red:

```
A start job is running for dev-disk-by\xZduuid-0ab076d8\x2d2d80\x2d44f9\x2d9076\x2d847266c6942c.device.
```

It hangs here for a minute and then shows the emergency mode notice.
I plugged in the original mechanical drive, recopied over the hyper-v folder thinking it was corrupt, but still get the same error. Then I decided to point the VM back to the vhdx on the original hard drive and now it gets the same error. I am getting very lost here and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check if the UUID matches with `blkid`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Which UUID do I want to match with blkid? I did run the blkid command and I see different UUIDs for each partition. I also noticed that when I ran blkid, it shows a line blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0. I assume that is for a floppy drive which I do not have enabled in the VM.